# Differentials of Measures in the context of Radon Nikodym Derivatives.

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, radon-nikodym

I first note that a similar question was asked here: [Calculating Radon Nikodym derivative](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/588442/calculating-radon-nikodym-derivative), though the explicit steps used to calculate the derivative were not made clear.

Over measurable space $([0,1],\mathcal{B}_{[0,1]}), \mu:=\nu+\delta_{0}.$

$\forall A\in\mathcal{B}_{[0,1]}$ define $\nu(A):=|A|.$

Finally, $\delta_{0} $ is the dirac measure with criterion of measured set containing $0$ in order to evaluate to 1.

$\mu >>\nu$ is clear and therefore $d\nu/d\mu$ exists.

$d\nu/d\mu \overset{*}= \frac{\nu(dy)}{\mu(dy)}=\frac{|dy|}{|dy|+\delta_{0}(dy)} = 1/\frac{|dy|+\delta_{0}(dy)}{|dy|} =1/(1+\delta_{0}(dy)/|dy|)$.
It is immediately apparent at this step, however, that this derivative will always be nonzero. Thus, I did something wrong in my calculation (and would like some help seeing where I went wrong). * is due to [Notation when integrating with respect to a measure](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3023225/notation-when-integrating-with-respect-to-a-measure) and is where I imagine I went wrong.

**UPDATE**:

It is clear that $\nu(A)=\int_{A}d\nu= \int_{A}\frac{d\nu}{d\mu}d\mu\Leftarrow \frac{d\nu}{d\mu}=\mathbf{1}_{\{X/0\}}$ to cancel out the dirac measure part in $\mu$ when it is not measure $0$, however, can the derivative be calculated from the differentials in some way or is it purely determined through the integral?

Comment: The "differential" is just notation and is defined by the integral equation.

Comment: @user251257 Interesting... is this why SDEs are typically interpreted in the integral equation form https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stochastic_differential_equation#Use_in_probability_and_mathematical_finance?

Comment: As stated in the wikipedia article, SDE is an integral equation. The "differential equation" is just informal notation.

Comment: @user251257 I see, thank you for pointing that out! I wasn't sure as to why SDEs were formally integral equations until now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your analysis was basically correct, and will be made rigorous below. At
$$
\frac1{1+\frac{\delta_0(dy)}{|dy|}}
$$
look what happens when $dy$ is around $0$. Then $|dy|$ is infinitely small,while $\delta_0(dy)=1$. Therefore, the above is $\frac1{1+\frac10}=\frac1{\infty}=0$, so the derivative is equal to $0$ at $y=0$, as expected. You were think $1/\text{stuff}$ could not be zero, but you forgot about stuff $=\infty$.

---

To get a differential characterization of $\frac{d\nu}{d\mu}$, it can shown that for $\mu$ a.e. $x$, you have
$$
\frac{d\nu}{d\mu}(x)=\lim_{\epsilon\to 0}\frac{\nu((x-\epsilon,x+\epsilon)\cap [0,1])}{\mu((x-\epsilon,x+\epsilon)\cap [0,1])}.
$$
This is a generalization of the Lebesgue differentiation theorem. I do not know what the standard reference for this is, but chapter 6.3 of [these notes](https://www.math.cuhk.edu.hk/course_builder/1617/math5012/Real%20Analysis_Chapter_6.2017.pdf) has a proof.

Now, when $x\neq 0$, then both the numerator and denominator are equal for all small enough $\epsilon$, so the limit is $1$. However, when $x=0$, the numerator will tend to zero while the denominator will tend to $1$. This shows that 
$$
\frac{d\nu}{d\mu}=1_{(0,1]}\qquad \mu \;a.e.
$$

Comment: I see. This is surprising as I thought it would be the case that because $\mu$ is not absolutely continuous w.r.t. $\nu$ that perhaps $ (\frac{\nu(dy)}{\mu(dy)})^{-1}$ does not exist as in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radon%E2%80%93Nikodym_theorem#Properties. How is it then that my inversion of the original density was proper?

Comment: $(\frac{\nu(dy)}{\mu(dy)})^{-1}$ always exists when $\frac{\nu(dy)}{\mu(dy)}$ exists, though it might be infinite. It is only $\frac{\mu(dy)}{\nu(dy)}$ which may not exist. If $\frac{\mu(dy)}{\nu(dy)}$ exists, then it equals $(\frac{\nu(dy)}{\mu(dy)})^{-1}$. @BayesIsBae

Comment: That is very interesting!

Comment: Well, we are working over the measurable space $([0,1],\mathcal B_{[0,1]})$, so I was making sure all of the subsets actually lived in that space.

Comment: Sorry about that - I realized only after asking in a previous comment